# Iterating remap tables in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, modelbuilder, iterator, reclassify

I'm new to ModelBuilder and have successfully used iterators for other things, but I'm having an issue with one particular model...

I have one raster file showing direction to nearest coast ("CoastDir") and I need to reclassify this into 8 separate binary maps representing the 8 compass directions. I figured the easiest way to do this (especially as it's something I have to do fairly regularly) was by creating a geodatabase containing 8 remap tables representing the directions, called N, NE, E, SE, S,... etc.

For example: Table "N" is

[image]

My model looks like the image below:

[image]

[image]

My iterator is set up with the basic geodatabase input and no other settings.

My problem is that it's not iterating properly. It's carrying out the reclassification dozens of times, but only on the "N" table, and overwriting the output, instead of moving onto the next table.

I tried renaming the Input Remap Table as "%Name%" instead of "N", but that didn't work either, but the format above has worked successfully for raster iterations.

I'd rather not delve into python if possible, as I'm building a series of tools, all in ModelBuilder, and I'm even less familiar with scripting. I will also need to do similar reclassifications on more directional rasters.

Do you know what I may be doing wrong?

I've googled an awful lot and am none the wiser! I'm using ArcGIS 10.4.1.

Comment: Can you amend your question to show how you have set up the iterator?